# ArcGIS Pro and Python 3 Inabilities

Tags: python, arcgis-pro

I have a map automation script that I have been using in ArcMap 10.5 with Python 2.7. I just learned the in's and out's of ArcGIS for Pro and would like to migrate my processing to Pro. It's taking a while to migrate the Python 2.7 code into something that will take in the Python 3 module of Pro, but I think for the most part, I've been able to translate my code.

With the exception of a couple of arcpy functions, so I wanted to see if anyone had any insight into how to do something. In my code, after selecting certain features, I have the code (2.7) use:

```
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

When I try to run this in Pro, it doesn't like it. It appears that "zoomToSelectedFeatures" is no longer supported in Python 3? Does anyone know a workaround to move the map automatically to the selected features in an automation script?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the Analyze Tools for PRO tool.
input your 2.7 py script and the result will be a .txt file highlighitng what needs to be changed (and telling you what to change it to)
see here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/analyzetoolsforpro.htm

for df.zoomtoselectedfeatures is now replaced with the following:

```
zoomToAllLayers ({selection_only}, {symbolized_extent})
```

*Modifies the MapFrame view to match the extent of all layers or selected layers in a map.*

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/mapframe-class.htm

[image]

This is the ESRI Sample Code Snippet.
[image]

you need to replace `zoomToBookmark` with `zoomToAllLayers(selection_only)`

Comment: I used the Analyze Tools for Pro tool and all it told me was that I was missing parentheses in my print functions; it didn't tell me about all of the other items I had to correct through error checking in the Python window.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: did the following fix your issue? I tested on my end and it worked.

Comment: I'm trying to work it in, but it's not identifying that function. It fails and tells me that 'Map' or 'ArcGISProject' object has no attribute 'zoomToAllLayers'

Comment: you need to understand there is no more arcpy.mapping its now arcpy.mp. read it form here http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm

Comment: I've gotten that far in knowing that things have changed, but I'm not seeing how to call out that function. I have a feature selected, so what I'm trying to do now is to invoke 'zoomToAllLayers'. I've tried 'arcpy.mp.zoomToAllLayers()', 'm.zoomToAllLayers()', 'aprx.zoomToAllLayers()'

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I still get: 'ArcGISProject' object has no attribute 'zoomToAllLayers'. I expect to see that function popup in the suggested functions when I type it, but it's not. I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1 so I should I have that available? Also tried running Pro as an admin.

Comment: where are you executing the code from? IDLE, within PRO? CMD?

Comment: From within Pro. Where did you run the function from?

Comment: The code above, I don't think is correct. You're calling `zoomToAllLayers` off the project object. I think you need to go a level deeper and go off a `MapFrame` (as you've pointed out in your help URL)

Comment: used mf in updated answer.

Comment: I've used that code and sorry, but I'm still getting the "object has no attribute 'zoomToAllLayers'" message in Pro. Can someone confirm that this can be done from within Pro?